# Creating Biq Query View With Partitioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a table in big query with 1 GB size. I create a view from this table with partitioning on created_at(timestamp) column. The view is useful for me but I want to write a query using created_at column. When I use this column , does the query run for whole data of view or run for only partitioned values? I want to limit usage of table like 500 MB. Is it possible with views by using partitioning column in where clause?

Comment: Check the validator (green check box) in the UI, which shows the number of bytes that will be processed for a query. Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new partitioned tables ([here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions) is the documentation) and copy the data into them.

To query a partitioned table you can use `_PARTITIONTIME`, for example:

```
SELECT
  [COLUMN]
FROM
  [DATASET].[TABLE]
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-03-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using actual BigQuery partitioned tables (there is no such thing as partitioned views) you'll be charged for all the data in the columns you access.

Comment: How can I'll be charged for only partitioned data?

Comment: You need to copy the data to a partitioned table.